# Plotting multiple countplots using seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have categorical variables in my data set, most of them are binary 0,1 but some are multi-class. I used `countplot` to plot the distribution.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(4,3,figsize=(17,13), sharex=True)
for i, feature in enumerate(cat_var_list):
    sns.countplot(df[feature],ax=axes[i%4, i//4])
```

`cat_var_list` has 12 variables.

However I found that the scale is 0,1 and variables that have multi-class outcomes 0,1,2 do not show properly.

For example, the plot looks like this:

[image]

However, for the variable Intro Election Status, the plot should look like this:

[image]

How can I make the plot show up properly in the multi plot grid format?

Answer (score 2):

I see your code works as expected with this sample data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (100,11)),
                  columns=list('abcdefABCDE'))
df['F'] = np.random.choice([0,1,2], 100)

cat_var_list = 'abcdefABCDEF'

f, axes = plt.subplots(4,3,figsize=(17,13), sharex=True)
for f,ax in zip(cat_var_list, axes.ravel()):
    sns.countplot(df[f], ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I removed sharex=True and it worked, I am still not sure why though.